# Javascript className changes aren't working

Tags: javascript, css

I have a small test page setup to test a sprite sheet I have. Each sprite in `sprites.css` looks like this...

```css
.a320_0 {
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 60px;
   height: 64px;
   background: url("images/sprites.png") no-repeat -787px -398px;
}
```

My page looks like this...

```js
var i = 0

function imageChange() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var hdg = i * 15;
    document.getElementById('image').className = "a320_" + hdg;
    i++;
    if (i < 24) {
      imageChange();
    }
  }, 1000)
}
imageChange()
```

```html
<div id='imageContainer'>
  <div id='image'></div>
</div>
```

I'm logging the class name during the loop and can see it changing and the names correspond to classes that exist in my style sheet. `sprites.css` and `sprites.png` are both in the images folder and the images folder is in the same directory as my page.

If I just copy one of the rules from my style sheet and put it directly onto my page and replace the name with `#image` for testing purposes I can display that particular image so my sprite coordinates are fine but if I do the same thing on my actual css file I don't get the same result leading me to believe that my style sheet might not be loading. Even if I just put the styles directly into my document and try to use `.className =` , it still doesn't work. I had this working recently but it doesn't seem to be working anymore. I'm kind of lost here...

Comment: you can check the final html directly from devtools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `document.getElementById("image").classList.add("a320_" + hdg);`.

```js
var i = 0;

function imageChange() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var hdg = i * 15;
    document.getElementById("image").classList.add("a320_" + hdg);
    i++;
    if (i < 24) {
      imageChange();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

imageChange();
```

```css
.a320_0 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 64px;
  background: url("https://source.unsplash.com/random") no-repeat -787px -398px;
}
```

```html
<div id='imageContainer'>
  <div id='image'></div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/LYbaKrZ)

Comment: This works. I have to remove the previous classes or it stops at around 90 degrees. (too many classes I guess?).

Answer (score 1):

While your script is correct, you seem to have made a major syntax error which is not giving you the desired results.

When adding class name to an HTML element using JavaScript, the syntax is as follows:

```
selector.property.action("property value");
```

for example your code should be:

```
document.getElementById('image').classList.add("a320_" + hdg);
```

So the correction needs to be done only in the javascript part:

```
var i = 0

function imageChange() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var hdg = i * 15;
    document.getElementById('image').classList.add("a320_" + hdg)
    i++;
    if (i < 24) {
      imageChange();
    }
  }, 1000)
}
imageChange()
```

Hope this was helpful!